# apache2 how to run multiple hosts listening on port 80 on the same server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

here the scenario:

I have `example.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect Permanent "/" "https://example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

the above works perfectly(it redirects to the configuration of `<VirtualHost *:443>...</VirtualHost>`),

now I'm trying to add another virtual host `dev.example.co.uk` to this server so it serves both websites on port `80`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ServerName dev.example.co.uk                                                                                                                                                                      


     Timeout 2400
     ProxyTimeout 2400
     ProxyBadHeader Ignore


     SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled
     SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/  retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/

</VirtualHost>
```

for some reason whenever I type `dev.example.co.uk` in a browser, it redirects to `example.com` which eventually redirects to `https://example.com`

I'm guessing it still picking up the first configuration.

basically what I really want is when I type `dev.example.co.uk` it picks the configuration of its own virtual host and not the first one.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is you second block actually inside a `<VirtualHost>` block or not? It's not clear from the excerpts given. Running `httpd -S` can be useful to make sure Apache is picking up the various virtual hosts correctly. Also you should ideally have a ServerName directive in each one.

Comment: @USDMatt soz bro , it was a typo, yes its inside <VirtualHost> block

Comment: @USDMatt `httpd` command not found, I'm running it on `ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: @USDMatt mate ur last part of ur comment did it for me. I feel so stupid, I was missing ServerName on the first configuration, please answer the question so I can accept it, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    #ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect Permanent "/" "https://example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Feel free to uncomment the serverAlias directive according to your needs